# No route found for "GET /connect"

Tags: symfony, routes, hwioauthbundle

Trying to use [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle)

> No route found for "GET /connect"
>   404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
>   1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »

https://gist.github.com/idlweb/6232475

Answer (score 0):

try to import more bundle routes into your app routing, not only the redirect.xml:

```
hwi_oauth_security:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/login.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_connect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/connect.xml"
    prefix: /connect

hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect
```

Comment: This didn't help me, the router does not match `/connect`